# I have a function $R \to C$, I want to plot it as the way we can plot parametric equations in the $R^2$. How to do it?

Tags: plotting, complex, parametric-functions

I have a real variable $t$ and a function $f(t)$ giving complex values. How to plot the function for $t$ in a given real interval? Also is there a way to do it in Wolfram Alpha website?

Comment: `f[t_]:=2 t+I t^2; ParametricPlot[{Re[f[t]],Im[f[t]]},{t,-3,3}]` works with Mathematica. `ParametricPlot[{Re[2 t+I t^2], Im[2 t+I t^2]},{t,-3,3}]` works with WolframAlpha.

Comment: You can also use `ReIm[f[t]]` instead of `{Re[f[t]], Im[f[t]]}` in Mathematica, although it produces the same result and WA seems not to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ReImPlot[2 t + I t^2, {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

That is a new built-in in V12 and newer: [`ReImPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReImPlot.html)

```
ReImPlot[{ArcSin[x], ArcCos[x]}, {x, -4, 4}, 
 PlotLabels -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

The input that suffices for WolframAlpha is simpler

```
WolframAlpha["2 t+I t^2 plot -pi to pi"]
```

[image]

```
WolframAlpha["{ArcSin[x],ArcCos[x]} plot -4 to 4"]
```

[image]

has some unexpected behavior with the desired interval. It does not show the continuation.

An introductory example is

```
ReImPlot[{Sqrt[1 - x^2], -Sqrt[x^2 - 1]}, {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]
This separates the branches of roots very neat.

```
AbsArgPlot[1 + Exp[-Abs[x]] Sin[I Sin[5 x]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]
[`AbsArgPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsArgPlot.html) is an acompanying function suiting the given criteria too.

A Mathematica example is the Nyquist plot:

```
h = 1/(s - 1/2)^2 /. s -> Exp[I \[Omega]]
ParametricPlot[{Re[h], Im[h]}, {\[Omega], 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]